# How to Join two tables with SUM in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join, sum

i have 2 tables

1.registros
[image]

2.servicios

[image]

what I wanna have is this: id,nombre,apellido,direccion,telefono servicios_pedidos of table 1 + sum of table 2 servicion.precios with table 1 registros.[servicio_perdidos].Value as Total a pagar

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your data.  See [mcve] for suggestions on how to provide examples and sample data.

Comment: As for the problem itself, the main reason you are facing it is because the table `registros` is designed incorrectly. The items stored in `servicios_pedidos` as a list should instead be stored in a separate table one item per row.